# rect's stroke doesn't follow the rect's radius

Tags: html, css, svg, stroke

I have a svg `rect` element that has some border radius by using `rx: 5; ry: 5`. I had to it a `stroke` of width `3`. Has you can see the `stroke` doesn't really follow the `rect` border, it seems less rounded:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="86" viewBox="0 0 300 86" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <style>
    .ctn {
      x: 0;
      y: 0;
      rx: 5;
      ry: 5;
      fill: blue;
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <rect width="300" height="86" class="ctn"/>
</svg>
```

Does have anyone an idea how I could make this `stroke` follow the parent's radius?

Comment: overflow: visible; to SVG to understand the issue

Comment: Omitting units in CSS for non-zero values is invalid for rx and ry. You should correct that and raise a bug in the browser that accepts it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh ok thanks for the advice it just feel kind of wrong to add units to a svg, the browser is chrome by the way.

Comment: If it feels wrong to use units, use attributes rather than CSS styles.